# How do i compile my app in Xcode with these errors - LibCurl

Tags: ios, xcode, libcurl, ios5, libssl

I've been porting icy (iPhone Debian-Based Package manager -- Jailbreak ) to iOS 5.
i've allready ported it once 4.0 came out, but now i'm getting errors wich untill now, i didn't solve.

When i build icy in iOS Simulator it has zero errors, but when i build it on my actual device, i'm getting the following errors :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_curl_easy_strerror", referenced from:
      -[URLDownload start] in URLDownload.o
  "_curl_easy_perform", referenced from:
      -[URLDownload start] in URLDownload.o
  "_curl_easy_init", referenced from:
      -[URLDownload initWithURL:delegate:resumeable:] in URLDownload.o
  "_curl_easy_setopt", referenced from:
      -[URLDownload initWithURL:delegate:resumeable:] in URLDownload.o
      -[URLDownload start] in URLDownload.o
  "_curl_easy_cleanup", referenced from:
      -[URLDownload dealloc] in URLDownload.o
  "_curl_slist_free_all", referenced from:
      -[URLDownload start] in URLDownload.o
  "_curl_slist_append", referenced from:
      -[URLDownload start] in URLDownload.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've allready updated the frameworks and stuff. i fixed like 200 errors and now i keep stuck with these errors.

There are also warnings, :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Samtulp6/Desktop/Infini-Dev/iOS/Projects/Icy/Fr0st's Source Code/Icy_Infini/Sources/Backend/Network/libcurl.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Samtulp6/Desktop/Infini-Dev/iOS/Projects/Icy/Fr0st's Source Code/Icy_Infini/Sources/Backend/Network/libcurl_i386.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Samtulp6/Desktop/Infini-Dev/iOS/Projects/Icy/Fr0st's Source Code/Icy_Infini/Sources/Backend/Network/libssl_i386.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Samtulp6/Desktop/Infini-Dev/iOS/Projects/Icy/Fr0st's Source Code/Icy_Infini/Sources/Backend/Network/libcrypto_i386.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
```

Anyone knows how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance

-Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the cURL Library you are using wasn't built for the `armv7` architecture used on the iPhone 4. Remove the `armv7` architecture from the Build Settings or rebuild the cURL Library with the armv7 architecture (fat library).

Comment: I'll just remove it from build settings because i have no idea how i would Rebuild cURL. :) tHANK YOU again

Comment: Now i get the following error :Check dependencies

[BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7, VALID_ARCHS=armv6).