# Can someone help me to compile Icy for iOS 5? ( Jailbreak )

Tags: xcode, curl, jailbreak, armv7

I'm having major trouble with Icy ( Cydia alternative )
( Like errors with cURL and ARMv7 )

So i was wondering if someone could help me to compile icy for iOS 5.
I already ported it to 4.x, but since 5.0 it crashes.

Back 4.x i didn't had any cURL / ARMv7 Errors.

Some people tell me to compile cURL for ARMv7, But i have no idea how, and i don't want to spend time at this, because i'll only need it once.

I'll credit you :)

- Samtulp6

Founder of Infini-Dev ( So i really need icy working :P )

Comment: Can you remove references to ios5. NDA is still in place

Comment: If you were *really* proficient, you'd know how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems the cURL Library you are using wasn't built for the `armv7`
>   architecture used on the iPhone 4. Remove the `armv7` architecture
>   from the Build Settings or rebuild the cURL Library with the armv7
>   architecture (fat library).

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205834/how-do-i-compile-my-app-in-xcode-with-these-errors-libcurl)